# Can two or more people own 1 stock in the US?

Tags: stocks, stock-markets, legal

How does joint stock ownership work in the US? Can multiple people own one stock? Can someone link me to legislation about this?

Answer (score 3):

A share of stock is an asset not much different than any other asset.  If the share is being held in a joint account, it's being jointly owned.  If the share is being held by a company with multiple owners then the share is owned by the various owners.  If you're married and in a community property state, then it's technically owned by both parties.

Comment: what if my friend and i wanted to joint own a stock? or a group of friends?

Comment: Then you'd need to open a joint brokerage account, or form some sort of business entity to open the account.

Comment: By the way, the term for one unit of stock in a company is "a share"; the phrase "a stock" usually refers to the group that a share belongs to, having a distinct ticker symbol. So you're jointly own some number of shares of a particular stock such as IBM or GPS or whatever. Not a big deal, but using the standard terminology makes the discussion clearer.